# Tag Synonym Request: TSV → CSV

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

Tab Separated Values [tsv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tsv) should be a synonym to [csv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/csv) as one of the **Character Separated Values** as it is a *delimiter* that can be used as an alternative to the comma <kbd>,</kbd>.

I know [csv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/csv) states it is for *comma separated values*, but the handling of both file-types is very similar and overlapping.

Currently there is one question tagged [tsv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tsv) (which is pretty surprising), but I don't see a reason to destroy it or re-tag it. A search for related tags for `tab separated values` did not reveal any additional tags.

A rudimentary [search reveals 14 questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=%22tab+separated%22+is%3Aquestion) that could also benefit from the [tsv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tsv) tag, but only one has the [csv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/csv) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added it as a synonym, found at [csv synonyms](https://superuser.com/tags/csv/synonyms). We'll see if it gets 4 votes to be approved.

I might also retag some questions about tsv to add more bulk to the tag.